# How to remove new line from Terminal on launch?

Tags: terminal, iterm, zsh

When I launch terminal, it always puts a new line at the beginning first.  I am using zsh and did install [ohmyzsh](https://ohmyz.sh), but I can't seem to find anything that would cause this behaviour.  Please see attached screenshot.  Using [powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k) theme.

I checked `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, and every other profile I can think of but can't figure it out.
[image]

New tab and pressed `return`
[image: new tab]

**UPDATE 2**: .zshrc BAD CONTENT IDENTIFIED

```
# Colorise the top Tabs of Iterm2 with the same color as background
# Just change the 18/26/33 wich are the rgb values
echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;18\a"
echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;26\a"
echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;33\a"
```

I don't know why these echo commands are causing that behavior, but when I comment out each one, the "new line" is less and less" until I have commented out all three.  I got the commands from [this medium.com post](https://medium.com/@Clovis_app/configuration-of-a-beautiful-efficient-terminal-and-prompt-on-osx-in-7-minutes-827c29391961) but it's only supposed to change the tab color.  I have removed them now, but tabs are blah.  Better than the line spacing.

Comment: Can you just press Enter/Return in a newly created tab and add a screenshot of the window?

Comment: What is the value of $PROMPT

Comment: @nohillside please see update

Comment: @mmmmmm please see update

Comment: Well that is not the value - try `echo $PROMPT`

Comment: Wow. If you disable the theme, does the problem disappear?

Comment: This is why OhMyZSH is a cancer.

Comment: @nohillside I mv'd .zshrc to .zshrc.bak and the behavior stopped.  Please help me find the culpable line entry.

Comment: @nohillside not sure why, but echo commands were the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

`echo` automatically adds a newline to the end of what it prints; since the escape sequence it's printing doesn't actually display anything on screen, this has the effect of printing a blank line. One option is to add the `-n` option to `echo` to tell it not to print the newline, but for complicated reasons some versions of `echo` will just print "-n" as part of their output (and then go ahead and print the newline too). `printf` is much more reliable for things like this (though it can be more complex to use correctly). See ["Why is printf better than echo?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) on the Unix & Linux stackexchange.

In this case, you can just replace `echo -e` with `printf`, and it should do the same thing but without the unwanted newlines:

```
printf "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;18\a"
printf "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;26\a"
printf "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;33\a"
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment out or remove the following three lines from ~/.zshrc

```
#echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;18\a"
#echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;26\a"
#echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;33\a"
```

Each `echo` actually creates a new line (on BigSur 11.2.3) and together they create 3 new lines on every new window/tab.